# parsing out text and non number characters from the data frame

Tags: regex, r

I have this data frame. I would like to have only numbers in the data frame. Clean it out so that no text, no %, and no -. I tried using gsub but when I use sub it converts my data frame to character and I cannot convert it back to a data frame again. Any ideas how I could get rid of characters and dashes from my data frame? I also need to ged rid of the emtpy lines.

```
    V1    V2     V3     V4    V5    V6     V7    V8    V9   V10
1  %user  %sys  %wait  %idle physc %entc  lbusy   app  vcsw phint
2  ----- ----- ------ ------ ----- ----- ------   --- ----- -----
3   36.4  13.1   13.9   36.6  9.26  57.9   28.0 34.96 26049  3492
4   31.1  11.2   12.6   45.1  7.81  48.8   25.9 37.85 17515  2754
5   33.2  13.4   13.2   40.3  8.69  54.3   26.9 35.67 23510  3265
6   34.0  12.8   13.7   39.4  8.77  54.8   26.5 35.19 25151  3305
7   32.7  12.4   13.6   41.3  8.49  53.0   25.9 35.97 25214  3201
8   33.4  13.7   12.5   40.3  8.76  54.7   27.1 36.50 23943  3391
4 %user  %sys  %wait  %idle physc %entc  lbusy   app  vcsw phint
25 ----- ----- ------ ------ ----- ----- ------   --- ----- -----
26  32.9  14.1   11.3   41.7  8.66  54.1   27.9 36.46 22438  3253
27  33.2  13.9   12.0   41.0  8.74  54.6   27.4 37.38 23838  3135
28  30.5  13.3   11.0   45.1  8.13  50.8   26.2 37.42 21912  2752
29  29.9  13.4   11.8   44.8  8.11  50.7   25.5 37.92 23030  2791
30  30.6  12.6   11.1   45.8  8.01  50.1   25.7 37.03 21844  2811
31  32.6  12.2   11.4   43.8  8.30  51.9   28.0 36.84 22227  2723
```

this does not work:

gsub("-","",xx)

Comment: how about `colwise` from the `plyr` package.  Then you can write something like: `xx<- na.omit(colwise(as.numeric)(xx))`. Or just get rid of the first two rows:  `xx[-1:2,]`

Comment: Did you mean you want to delete header and row 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the first two lines of the data.frame:

```
data1 <- data1[-(1:2),]
```

**Added comment.** It seems that the lines that you want to remove always start with "%user" or "-----". You could remove them like this. This is untested code because you did not provide a reproducible example.

```
data1[!(data1[,1]=="%user"|data1[,1]=="-----"),]
```

Comment: @P Lapointe, this wont work, since I have characters in midle and other places of the data frame.

Comment: Can you show a good example of your data.frame? You have no special characters in the current one.

Comment: @eddi, no that wont work. It converts text to numeric. I need to remove text from my data frame.

Comment: huh, it does exactly that - it removes any text from your data frame. Try his code.

Comment: oh yeah that was my suggestion too: coerce everything to numeric, producing NAs, then exclude the NAs. it will work so try it.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is try to coerce everything into `numeric`:

```
numerics_only <- apply(data, 2, as.numeric)
```

Attempting to coerce text into numeric will introduce `NA`s:

```
Warning messages:
1: In apply(data, 2, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

These you can suppress if you like. Then filter out all the rows that have NAs.

```
newdata <- na.omit(numerics_only)
```

Something along the lines of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that the approach with as.numeric() of course works:
(applied to your example copied to a text file)

```
> df <- read.delim("testdf.txt", sep = " ", as.is = T)[,-1]
> str(df)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ V1 : chr  "%user" "-----" "36.4" "31.1" ...
 $ V2 : chr  "%sys" "-----" "13.1" "11.2" ...
 $ V3 : chr  "%wait" "------" "13.9" "12.6" ...
 $ V4 : chr  "%idle" "------" "36.6" "45.1" ...
 $ V5 : chr  "physc" "-----" "9.26" "7.81" ...
 $ V6 : chr  "%entc" "-----" "57.9" "48.8" ...
 $ V7 : chr  "lbusy" "------" "28.0" "25.9" ...
 $ V8 : chr  "app" "---" "34.96" "37.85" ...
 $ V9 : chr  "vcsw" "-----" "26049" "17515" ...
 $ V10: chr  "phint" "-----" "3492" "2754" ...
> (df <- data.frame(na.omit(apply(df, 2, as.numeric))))
     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7    V8    V9  V10
1  36.4 13.1 13.9 36.6 9.26 57.9 28.0 34.96 26049 3492
2  31.1 11.2 12.6 45.1 7.81 48.8 25.9 37.85 17515 2754
3  33.2 13.4 13.2 40.3 8.69 54.3 26.9 35.67 23510 3265
4  34.0 12.8 13.7 39.4 8.77 54.8 26.5 35.19 25151 3305
5  32.7 12.4 13.6 41.3 8.49 53.0 25.9 35.97 25214 3201
6  33.4 13.7 12.5 40.3 8.76 54.7 27.1 36.50 23943 3391
7  32.9 14.1 11.3 41.7 8.66 54.1 27.9 36.46 22438 3253
8  33.2 13.9 12.0 41.0 8.74 54.6 27.4 37.38 23838 3135
9  30.5 13.3 11.0 45.1 8.13 50.8 26.2 37.42 21912 2752
10 29.9 13.4 11.8 44.8 8.11 50.7 25.5 37.92 23030 2791
11 30.6 12.6 11.1 45.8 8.01 50.1 25.7 37.03 21844 2811
12 32.6 12.2 11.4 43.8 8.30 51.9 28.0 36.84 22227 2723
Warnmeldungen:
1: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
2: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
3: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
4: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
5: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
6: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
7: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
8: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
9: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
10: In apply(df, 2, as.numeric) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
```